# Kotlin type inferrence failed

Tags: kotlin, type-inference, kotlin-null-safety

This kotlin code:

```
fun badKotlin(text: String?): Boolean {
    if (text == null) {
        return true
    }

    var temp = text
    if (false) {
        temp = Arrays.deepToString(arrayOf(text))
    } 

    return temp.isBlank() // <-- only safe (?.) or non null asserted (!!.) calls
}
```

does not compile with message: `only safe (?.) or non null asserted (!!.) calls are allowed on a nullable receiver of type String?`

But if I add `else`:

```
fun badKotlin(text: String?): Boolean {
    if (text == null) {
        return true
    }

    var temp = text
    if (false) {
        temp = Arrays.deepToString(arrayOf(text))
    } else {
        temp = Arrays.deepToString(arrayOf(text))
    }

    return temp.isBlank()
}
```

all compiled. So, why type inferrence failed?

If I change type of temp to `var temp: String = text` it is successfully copmiled! So, moreover, If we change assignment of temp like this: `temp = String.format("%s", text)` it is compiled too.

UPDATE:

Successfully copmpiled:

```
fun badKotlin(text: String?): Boolean {
    if (text == null) {
        return true
    }

    var temp = text
    if (false) {
        temp = String.format("%s", text)
    } 

    return temp.isBlank() // <-- only safe (?.) or non null asserted (!!.) calls
}
```

And this:

```
fun badKotlin(text: String?): Boolean {
    if (text == null) {
        return true
    }

    var temp: String = text
    if (false) {
        temp = Arrays.deepToString(arrayOf(text))
    } 

    return temp.isBlank() // <-- only safe (?.) or non null asserted (!!.) calls
}
```

Comment: `var temp = text` mean `temp` is nullable and `if(false)` block which have never happend was not make it become not null. In case 2, `Arrays.deepToString(arrayOf(text))` always executes so that it makes temp become not null.

Comment: Yes, but see [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49248224/kotlin-type-inferrence-failed?noredirect=1#comment85500131_49248252) to answer

Comment: I suggest to use `isNullOrBlank()` method instead.

Comment: `var temp: String = text` and `temp = String.format("%s", text)` make the `temp` not null. Therefore, your code can compiled. `var temp: String = text` means the `temp` is String, not null, and take value from `text`. `var temp: String? = text` means the `temp` is String, nullable, and take value from `text`

Comment: So, my question is why `String.format("%s", text)` make `temp` not null, and `Arrays.deepToString(arrayOf(text))` make `temp` nullable?

Comment: Both `String.format("%s", text)` and `Arrays.deepToString(arrayOf(text))` is always return a non-null String, please refer their detailed implementation. In your first case, condition of `if` block is always false so it's never run the `Arrays.deepToString(arrayOf(text))` inside, and that `temp` will keep the reference from `text` (nullable String) without change

Comment: @JunBach But the compiler knows `String.format` never returns `null` (its return type is `String`); it doesn't know this about `Arrays.deepToString` (its return type is `String!`) because it isn't part of the _Kotlin_ standard library.

Comment: @alexey-romanov It is, you are right

Comment: @alexey-romanov can you link to fact, when type `String!` will be inferrented to `String?`? Kotlin by default prefer nullable type for JVM types? I think, the compiler is not smart enough in this case

Comment: Sure, it could be smarter, but `var` complicates smart casts, as documented, and this seems a pretty weird edge case. You can try reporting it as a bug.

Comment: Better Kotlin-like style would be `val temp = if (false) Arrays.deepToString(arrayOf(text)) else text` without `var` and it works fine.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov I found the answer, thanks to your [link](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html#smart-casts). Smart casting is not applicable in first case of my question, because local variable `temp` was modified between check and the usage.

Comment: I've also edited the answer to mention it.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be thinking that after

```
if (text == null) {
    return true
}
```

the type of `text` is refined to `String` instead of `String?`.

But it seems like it isn't; instead the compiler inserts a smart cast when it sees `text` is used where a `String` is required. In the

```
var temp = text
```

line there is no reason to insert a cast, so the compiler doesn't, and the type of `temp` is `String?`.

If you write

```
var temp: String = text
```

the cast *is* necessary and so the compiler does insert it.

If you write

```
if (...) {
    temp = Arrays.deepToString(arrayOf(text))
} else {
    temp = Arrays.deepToString(arrayOf(text))
}
```

the compiler sees that whatever happens, `temp` has been assigned a value of [platform type `String!`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#null-safety-and-platform-types) which again can be smart-cast to `String`. Without a `else` branch, this doesn't happen.

EDIT:

Curiously, if you just remove `if` and leave

```
fun badKotlin(text: String?): Boolean {
    if (text == null) {
        return true
    }

    var temp = text
    
    return temp.isBlank()
}
```

it does compile, and if my explanation was complete I wouldn't expect it to. So the compiler does maintain information needed for the smart cast, but it appears not to get applied because

> More specifically, smart casts are applicable according to the following rules: ...
>
> - `var` local variables - **if the variable is not modified between the check and the usage**, is not captured in a lambda that modifies it, and is not a local delegated property;

In the `if-else` case, the assignments in two branches together serve as another check; in the `if`-only, the one branch doesn't.

Comment: Thanks, interesting... And what you say about sample in question with `if-else` construction? Why there is compiled?

Comment: Wow, I want to trust you, so can you please provide links about necessary and unnecessary smart casting?

Comment: This is simply my interpretation. The documentation is at https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html#smart-casts, but it isn't too detailed.

Answer (score 1):

By assigning `text` to `temp`, the type of temp will become `String?`, too. Like this:

```
var temp: String? = text
```

Since your `if (false)` will never be executed it does not have any effect on the code. The `else` adds a block that always gets executed (since it basically means `if (true)`) and assigns a `String` to `temp` that is not nullable. Since temp is not nullable in the second example, you don’t have to use safe-call operators anymore...

Comment: Hm, but if I change type of temp to `var temp: String = text` it is successfully copmiled! So, moreover, If we change assignment of `temp` like this: `temp = String.format("%s", text)` it is compiled too.

Comment: The interesting part is why `if (text == null) { return true }` doesn't make `text` a `String`.